# How importing packages and subpackages actually work?

Tags: python, python-module, python-packaging

I've been trying to understand how importing packages and subpackages works in Python. Based on what I understood from [realpython.com](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/#python-packages), a package is simply a directory that contains python modules and a `__init__.py` file in which you could include an `__all__` list object containing all the objects to import should you use an `import *` statement. On top of that, if you want to include more subpackages, each one should be a subdirectory with a `__init__.py` file in it.

So, let's assume I'm working on a project that looks something like this where `my_pckg/` is a package I'm trying to create.

```
Project/
├── main.py
└── my_pckg/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── functions.py
    └── abc/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── A.py
```

My understanding is that if I want to use a function `func_1()` from the `functions` module, I would have to run any of the following:

```
import my_pckg.functions as pckg_fun
pckg_fun.func_1()

from my_pckg.functions import func_1
func_1()
```

Equally, if I want to import a function `func_A()` from the `A` module of the `abc` subpackage, all I would have to do is use any of the following options:

```
import my_pckg.abc.A as pckg_A
pckg_A.func_A()

from my_pckg.abc.A import func_A
func_A()
```

Now, when I'm working with Python libraries like Numpy and I want to use the `randn()` function from the random subpackage, for example, I can simply do

```
import numpy as np
np.random.randn(2)
```

Whereas if I run the following snippet

```
import my_pckg as mp
mp.functions.func_1()
```

or

```
import my_pckg as mp
mp.abc.A.func_A()
```

I get an error like this one:

```
>>> mp.functions.func_1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'my_pckg' has no attribute 'functions'
```

or this one, respectively

```
>>> mp.abc.A.func_A()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'my_pckg' has no attribute 'abc'
```

So, I'm guessing that either there's more to creating modules that I thought, or I'm not understanding how modules like NumPy actually work.

Finally this joke by Mitch Hedberg truly summarizes the way I feel about all this:

> They say the recipe for Sprite is lemon and lime, but I tried to make it at home, there's more to it than that. [...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `__init__.py` add import statements of the stuff you want to use from that module when you import only the module.

Using your example, in `my_pckg/__init__.py`, you would have

```
import functions
import abc.A
```

After that, you should be able to do what you described with no problems.

Edit: Best practices for import within packages are slightly different. Even with modules in the same folder, instead of directly importing, you should import from `.` like this:

```
from . import functions
from abc import A
```

The side effect to the second line is that you will directly call `mp.A.func_A()` instead of `mp.abc.A.func_A()`

Answer (score -1):

Package submodules are available as attributes on their package if any code, *anywhere in the program*, has imported that submodule. When you first `import numpy`, NumPy itself [imports its own submodules](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.24.2/numpy/__init__.py#L149-L154), letting you access them without you explicitly importing those submodules:

```
from . import linalg
from . import fft
from . import polynomial
from . import random
from . import ctypeslib
from . import ma
```